# How to close multi-image popups on one button

Tags: javascript

Im trying to close three modals on one button after calling ID and it seem it doesnt work. The playagain() button function is to start over the game and to close 3 popups at the same time.

HTML

```
<div id="youwon">
    <img src="youwon.jpg">
</div>
<div id="youlose">
    <img src="youlose.jpg">
</div>
<div id="tied">
    <img src="tied.jpg">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function playAgain() {
    if (all==0)
        if(confirm("This will restart the game and clear all the current scores. OK?")) 
            reset();
    if (all>0)
        reset();
}
function reset() {
    all = 0;
    $("#youwon","#youlose","#tied").remove();  <---------
    document.images.A.src= blank;
    document.images.B.src= blank;
    document.images.C.src= blank;
    document.images.D.src= blank;
    document.images.E.src= blank;
    document.images.F.src= blank;
    document.images.G.src= blank;
    document.images.H.src= blank;
    document.images.I.src= blank;
    if (t==0) { t=2; myChoice(); }
    t--;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want to remove them? Or just hide them?

Comment: Yes I need to hide them and I replaced it with hide() and it worked - thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly with `hide()`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors (they allow commas). Use:

```
$("#youwon, #youlose, #tied").hide();
```

Comment: Yeah that worked - thanks!